# Magento2 Controller Not overriding

Tags: magento2, controllers, di

I add the controller in my local but it not working.

di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost" type="Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account\CreatePost" />
 </config>
```

module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Module configuration.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Tychons_Registration" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

Createpost.php

```
    namespace Company\Custom\Controller\Catalog\Product;

class View extends Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account\CreatePost

{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "create post";exit;

    }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "tychons/registration",
    "description": "Manage Registartion",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Tychons\\Registartion\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

registratio.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Module configuration
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Tychons_Registation',
    __DIR__
);
```

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: All below answers are working, There's wrong with your code. Find the error and correct it.

Comment: You should really take more care when coding: "psr-4": `Tychons\\Registartion\\"`  should be REGISTRATION

Answer (score 1):

You did the mistake at Createpost.php

The over-rewritten class `Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account\CreatePost` definition is totally wrong.

```
<?php 
namespace Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account;

class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost

{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "create post";exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but not working

Comment: You do clear cache and the do  di compile. Need to recompile the class

Comment: yes, cleared the cache run the di compile and static-content:deploy also run

Comment: Ensure that you have registration.php and composer.json on your module and also check the module.xml and di files has right  stucture

Comment: Added the composer.json and registration.php file please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
namespace Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account;

class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost

{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "create post";exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but not working

Answer (score 0):

Your `Createpost.php` contains a class called 'View' not 'Createpost' and your namespace is nothing like what is set in your prefernence in di.xml..

If it should be called CreatePost, your preference should be:

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost" type="Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account\CreatePost" />
```

and your Createpost:

```
namespace Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account;

class Createpost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost

{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "create post";exit;

    }
}
```

edit:

On top of that your psr-4 has spelling mistakes in your composer.json; your module registration.php registers the module under a wrong name;

To put it bluntly, your code it a complete mess.

Comment: Thanks for reply but not working

Comment: did you `setup:di:compile`?

Comment: I did the di compile also not working

Answer (score 0):

You did mistake in Createpost.php file, the code should be like this.

```
namespace Tychons\Registration\Controller\Account;

class CreatePost extends Company\Custom\Controller\Catalog\Product

{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "create post";exit;
    }
}
```

Then run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If you are using default or developer mode then run this command instead of above command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Then run below command to flush cache.

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

To get more information about controller override you can click this link:
https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/